# PHP include() returning value inconsistent or my ignorance?

Tags: php, types, include

Oh well, maybe it's my ignorance, but PHP documentation about [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) statement says *take care when comparing return value*:

```
<?php
// won't work, evaluated as include(('vars.php') == 'OK'), i.e. include('')
if (include('vars.php') == 'OK') {
    echo 'OK';
}

// works
if ((include 'vars.php') == 'OK') {
    echo 'OK';
}
?>
```

But this is what i've experienced; `boolean false` in case of fail, `int 1` if success:

```
$exists = 'Found.php';
var_dump((include $exists)); // Type is: int, value is: 1

$notexists = 'NotFound.php';
var_dump((include $notexists)); // Type is: boolean, value is: false
```

***Is this my bad? Why returning value is inconsistent (meaning not always `boolean`, for example) and differs from PHP documentation?***

Comment: `1 == true` in loose comparison...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this is exactly what the documentation states:

> $bar is the value 1 because the include was successful. ...
>   If the file can't be included, FALSE is returned and E_WARNING is issued.

When it becomes inconsistent is when you actually return something in the included file,
e.g. in Found.php:

```
<?php
return 'Returned from Found.php';
```

And then

```
include 'Found.php'; // -> Returns "Returned from Found.php"
```

It is also worth reading up on how booleans evaluate in PHP:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. It's the same in case of warnings or any other output from the included file?